# Careers feature request: Consultant

Tags: feature-request, jobs

In objectives, as well as full time and part time jobs, an interesting option (for me at least) would be Consultant, meaning a few hours/meetings.

Like me, many people have full time jobs but also work a few hours here and there as consultants.

There is no easy centralized way to find consultants that I know of. Careers 2.0 could be it.

Comment: Isn't this what the "Temporary contract" option is for? That's how I view it in any case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Though temporary contract can apply to a rather broad variety of situations I guess. Consultancy would be a bit more specific and useful if that's what you're offering/looking for.

Comment: @Bart: I guess so, but even 'Consultancy' is a broad term. Perhaps that would work better in the personal statement?